# How View is resolved in Prism

Tags: c#, silverlight, prism

I am newbie in using Prism. I have created a sample application to understand it. I have some queries on, how it is working.

**Question 1:**

```
    public class HelloModuleCls : IModule
    {
        IRegionManager regionManager;
        IUnityContainer container;

        public void Initialize()
        {
        RegisterViewAndServices(); // Injecting occurs here

            if (regionManager.Regions.ContainsRegionWithName("ViewHolder"))
            {
                regionManager.Regions["ViewHolder"].Add
                (
                ***container.Resolve().View***
                );
            }
        }

        protected void RegisterViewAndServices()
        {
            //since angular brace is not appearing, I am using ( , )....
            container.RegisterType(IHelloView, HelloViewUC)();
            container.RegisterType(IHelloViewModel, EmployeeVM)();
        }
    }

    public class EmployeeVM : INotifyPropertyChanged, IHelloViewModel
    {        
        public EmployeeVM(IHelloView targetview)
        {

        }
    }
```

Upon hitting the line, ***container.Resolve().View***,
the ctor of the VM, gets executed with, view type got injected in the ***param "targetview".***

***1. So, what will happen behind the scene, when that line got a hit...?***

**Question 2:**
**Project Name:- HelloModule (Another Silvelight Class Library referred in the startup Silverlight Application)**

```
    public class HelloModuleCls : IModule
    {
        public HelloModuleCls(IRegionManager rm, IUnityContainer um)
        {
        regionManager = rm;
        container = um;
        }
    }
```

**(Shell.Xaml)** (In Startup Silverlight Application)

```
<ContentControl Prism:RegionManager.RegionName="ViewHolder" Grid.Row="0">
</ContentControl>
```

This Module is in another project. I am having the Region in the startup project. I have seen that, in the ctor of the HelloModuleCls, the region got which is used in the Startup project, got injected perfectly...

***2. So, how the prism is passing those regions..... Is it like, once the region got created, then it will be injected to all the available Modules ctor or some other concept.***

May I kindly know, how this is working out, So I can able to understand more.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Answer 1: it resolve the *one* view, normally you want to register views with some key to be able to differentiate them.

Answer 2: it's the other way round, the regions exist in the application and the modules use them. They need to somehow know the name of the region, of course.

Unsorted comments:

- `RegisterType<ISomeInterface, OneOfItsImplementations>()` lives in  the `Microsoft.Practices.Unity` namespace, so add `using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;` to "see the angular brace appearing"
- use something like `regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("MyRegion", typeof(AView))` to make the view automatically appear in the region
- to switch views in a region, have a look at prism's navigation features, like `RegisterTypeForNavigation` and `RequestNavigate`
- the view uses the viewmodel, not the other way round. The viewmodel normally doesn't know about the view.